# Store and fetch NSMutableArray in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, nsmutablearray

I would like to save the `NSMutableArray` to `Core-Data` when my application terminates/goes into background and I would like to load the `NSMutableArray` when my application launches/becomes active.

I don't have a very good understanding of `Core-Data` yet. This is my first time working with it. I've looked at a bunch of videos, tutorials, previous Stackoverflow questions and Apple's documentation. I think what I am trying to do falls under the Non-Standard Persistent Attributes chapter in Apple's `Core-Data` documentation.

I have set up an Entity called TableViewList and I have given it an attribute called List of type transformable.

Here is my AppDelegate.h and .m code. All advice would be wonderful.

## AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property(nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property(nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property(nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

-(NSString *) applicationDocumentsDirectory;    
@end
```

## AppDelegate.m

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize managedObjectModel;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator;
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newContact;
    newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TableViewList" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSData *arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:ListArray];        
    [newContact setValue:arrayData forKey:@"list"];
    NSError *error = nil;        
    [context save:&error];


}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:[NSBundle allBundles]];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
    NSURL *url = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent: @"App1.sqlite"];
    [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:nil error:nil];
    managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;


    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TableViewList" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"unable to execute fetch request");
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
}
```

The result array returns an empty array. I don't think I'm saving and fetching the array correctly. Thanks in advance for your help!

I used [this link](http://blog.soff.es/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding) to implement `NSCoding` in my object.

Comment: Two questions: 1. What is the type of the `list` attribute in your data model? 2. What kind of objects are in the array that you're saving?

Comment: @TomHarrington 1. `list` is type transformable. 2. the object is a custom NSObject that has three properties. two are NSString and one is NSUInteger.

Comment: Are you sure you want/need to use a Transformable?  You seem to be storing a list as a single attribute on a single object.  You could instead have an entity that has two string attributes and one integer, and save a separate instance of that entity for each object in your array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK there are several things to mention here:

1. In `applicationDidEnterBackground`, the first half of the method configures a new managed object context that you never use. Since you then get a different managed object context from the app delegate, you don't the one you create here, so the code that creates a new context can be deleted. You probably also want to use the app delegate's context in `applicationDidBecomeActive`, though what you have isn't necessarily wrong.
2. You don't ever save changes. You need to call `save:` on the managed object context to save data to the persistent store file.
3. In order to use a transformable property, the data you're saving must conform to `NSCoding` (because Core Data doesn't know how to transform arbitrary classes, and `NSCoding` is how you tell it what to do). `NSArray` does, but it's also important that everything in the array also conforms. If your custom class does that, you're OK. If not, you'll need to fix that to save the array or find a different way to save your data.
4. I don't believe that you're going to get a *mutable* array back, no matter what you do. Once you get saving and fetching working, you'll get an immutable array as the value of the `list` property. So you'll need to call `mutableCopy` if you need the array to be mutable.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have made your suggested changes. Right now I am in the process of conforming my object to NSCoding because I am getting an unrecognized selector sent to instance error. I will let you know how that works out. and hopefully if I run into another problem we could discuss it some more.

Comment: Now that I have implemented `NSCoding` it seems that I am able to save data in `appplicationDidEnterBackground`. Also in `applicationDidBecomeActive` I am seeing the right number of table objects but they haven't been transformed back yet. This is the output that I see: "<TableViewList: 0x7f8b125b1e10> (entity: TableViewList; id: 0xd000000000080002 <x-coredata://D44FF3E8-F18C-49E6-A281-9809AAA455CF/TableViewList/p2> ; data: <fault>)" I am unsure how to unarchive the data from the result array. Thanks again.

Comment: You're fetching `TableViewList` objects, and that looks normal. You would need to get the value of the `list` property to get the array back.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I was able to get the value of the `list` property. :) i used the following code in my AppDelegate.m   `TableViewList *tableViewList = [result firstObject]; NSMutableArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:tableViewList.list]; NSLog(@"%@",array);` the output was my original custom object. i'll update my code soon.